# Using $dx$ for $h$ in the definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, notation

Is it mathematically correct to write
$$f'(x)=\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx},$$
rather than
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}?$$
If not, what is the difference?  If so, why isn't this notation used from the beginning?  My feeling for the latter is that it would align the derivative more with the inverse of the indefinite integral.

Comment: For educators: follow the notation in the textbook.  Even if both of these are correct, it does not help students at this level to see variant notations.

Comment: In smooth infinitesimal analysis one writes $f(x+dx)=f(x)+f'(x)dx$, where $dx$ is an infinitesimal, without any limits.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I would be more convinced by that if I ever saw any evidence that my students read the textbook, or if I found a textbook that I could wholeheartedly recommend that they read.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To use $$f'(x)=\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$$ is mathematically correct **if** $dx$ is the name for a real variable. (If it should be something else it needs to be made clear what it should be.)

It would also be correct to say 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\text{small}\to 0}\frac{f(x+\text{small})-f(x)}{\text{small}}$$ with the understanding that $\text{small}$ is the name of a real variable.

An issue I see with what you propose is though that $dx$ is *not* a common notation for a real variable, but rather something else. What exactly $dx$ means, depends on the context, but typically it is not used to denote a real number.

A very related notation that is more common is 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

The idea is that the $\Delta x$ is a finite difference, as opposed to an infinitesimal difference that might be denoted by $dx$ (where the latter notion might or might not be made precise).

Personally I prefer to use just an $h$ or something similar, to emphasis that it is just some real parameter there nothing special or mysterious. To name it $dx$ or $\Delta x $ goes counter this so I would not do it.

Comment: Agreed that it is mathematically correct if $dx$ is the name for a real variable.  I do use it that way, despite all the $h$s in the textbook, because I think it is important to emphasize that the role played by this variable is that of a *small change in* $x$.  And I think insisting on writing $\Delta x$ when the small change is "finite" is misguided pedantry, especially in textbooks that a few sections later on when talking about "differentials" _define_ $dx = \Delta x$!

Answer (score 7):

In the other examples, one can make sense of $\mathrm{d}x$ in a consistent way: e.g. if we model it as differential forms, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is a ratio between two differential forms,  $\int \sin x \, \mathrm{d} x$ is the anti-derivative of a differential form, and $\int_a^b \sin x \, \mathrm{d} x$ is the integral of a differential form along a (directed) path. One can even reasonably extend differentiable functions to the exterior algebra, and make literally true statements like $f(x + \mathrm{d}x) - f(x) = f'(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

However, if one were to write the calc-1 definition of derivative as
$$ \lim_{\mathrm{d}x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \mathrm{d}x) - f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} $$
the $\mathrm{d}x$ here doesn't represent anything resembling a differential form at all. The superficial similarity to my last remark in the previous paragraph makes things *worse*, not *better*, since it would conflate the distinct ideas, and thus make it harder to intuitively arrive at what $\mathrm{d} x$ means.

Comment: This definitely sheds some light on the comparison between $h$ and $dx$. I suppose that to use the latter in the sense of the definition of the derivative, and defining $dx$ as the same differential form as integration, the definition would not make sense since $dx$ is _already_ infinitesimally small. That is, we'd get $0/0$ for every derivative when making $dx\to 0$. Is this a right conclusion?

Comment: I disagree that $dx$ here doesn't represent anything resembling a differential form.  In fact, it resembles a differential form quite a lot!  If we free ourselves from insisting that a "differential form" must always depend *linearly* on $dx$, then we can consider $f(x+dx)-f(x)$ to indeed be a differential form (a function depending on both a variable and a small change in that variable) that is linearly approximated by another differential form $dy$ (essentially by definition of the latter).

Answer (score 4):

A sitenote: When you leave classical analysis and you take [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis), then you have infinitesimals in your underlying theory (they are part of the so called [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)). In this theory you can write $$\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$$ with $dx$ being an infinitesimal. This gives a number which difference to $f'(x)$ is only an infinitesimal (see the comments to this question). No [hocus pocus](http://www.tienchiu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/then-a-miracle-occurs-logic.jpg) necessary ;-)

Comment: ... without the need for a limit?

Comment: Yes, in non-standard analysis you need no limit to define the derivative. The reason is, that you have infinitesimals which don't exist in classical analysis and which you can use in the definition of the derivative.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271476/why-it-is-absolutely-mistaken-to-cancel-out-differentials/1273083 for more details

Comment: As a side note, for differentiability, the (standard part of the) quotient can't depend upon which non-zero infinitesimal is used, so it takes at least one explicit quantifier to define the derivative and to make sure it exists in the first place.

Comment: You still need hocus pocus to define the derivative: NSA just picks a different magic (albeit, arguably conceptually simpler magic).

Comment: +1, but: let E be the expression written in this answer. Note that in NSA, E is not the derivative f'(x). The derivative equals the *standard part* of E.

Comment: @Vandermonde: Normally we only care about differentiating real functions, not hyperreal functions. That is, we define some real function $f$, and then the expression given in the answer is to be interpreted as an expression involving $f$'s nonstandard extension ${}^*f$.  In that situation, I think the only thing that has to be stated in the definition is that it should hold for both positive and negative $dx$. In any case the depth of quantifiers is at most 1, not 2 (as in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit). This is what we usually expect to gain with NSA: one less quantifier.

Comment: @BenCrowell:  Hmm? There are many cases of practical interest (e.g., convex functions) where the only obstacle to differentiability is a discrepancy between one-sided derivatives, but this is far from the only thing one need worry about; for example $x$ times the Dirichlet function shouldn't be differentiable at zero, the difference quotient being 1 or 0 according as $dx \in {}^*\mathbb{Q}$. Your point about hiding quantifiers is well taken, though -- and I think being baked into the hyperreal construction reduces them from 3 to 1 since after $\delta$ would ordinarily come $x$-within-$\delta$.

Comment: @Vandermonde: You're right.

Answer (score 1):

When Leibniz (co)invented the calculus, he also introduced the symbol $dx$ for an infinitesimal increment of the variable $x$. Today when the calculus is presented there is an immediate asymmetry between the independent variable $x$ and the dependent variable $y$ but to Leibniz $x$ and $y$ had equal rights; he was mostly working with curves in the $x,y$ plane. When you are dealing with more than one variable, it is important to indicate which variable is undergoing the increment.  Therefore the symbols $dx,dy$ are indispensable.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Can you elaborate on how this is related to possibly writing $dx$ for $h$ in the definition?